# output of System.out.format("%6f%n", 123.0); not as expected

Tags: java, format

I'm currently learning how to format in java and have encountered the following problem

I have

```
System.out.format("%6f%n", 123.0);
```

I expect the result to be `123.0` with one blank space at the left (i.e. the minimum length of output to be 6). However, instead I have got

```
123.000000 //with no blank space on the left
```

Why is this happening? Why is there six 0's after decimal point? Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Try using `%5.1f` instead.

Comment: Why would you expect one blank space on the left, when the string (`"123.0"`) is already 5 characters long?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. i meant 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the number of digits behind the decimal point. If you don't, it's assumed to be 6 digits. So you can do:

```
System.out.format("%6.1f%n", 123.0);
```

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> The number of digits in the result for the fractional part of m or a
>   is equal to the precision. **If the precision is not specified then the
>   default value is 6.** If the precision is less than the number of digits
>   which would appear after the decimal point in the string returned by
>   Float.toString(float) or Double.toString(double) respectively, then
>   the value will be rounded using the round half up algorithm.
>   Otherwise, zeros may be appended to reach the precision.

Comment: Thank you so much! This question has troubled me for hours now! Thanks to you now everything is clear!